# linker error when I use template and static variable

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to make something like this:

```
class A
{
    static pthread_mutex_t m;
public:
    template<typename T>
        static void TestFunc(T t) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    }
    static void Test()
    {
            TestFunc(13);
    }
};
```

But receive linker error:

> /tmp/cc1HN0fI.o: In function `void A::TestFunc<int>(int)':
>   TReaderThread.cpp:(.text._ZN1A8TestFuncIiEEvT_[_ZN1A8TestFuncIiEEvT_]+0xc): undefined reference to`A::m'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [all] Error 1

It seems that this error happens only when TestFunc is template function. It is small peace of code, I need that
TestFunc was template and my mutex was static variable. Is it possible to solve this issue in template approch?
P.S. Realy I need to do - implement tracer as singlton(with syncronization for output descriptor).

Comment: You defined `m`, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your `static pthread_mutex_t m;` is declared but is not defined. Add the following line in your *.cpp implementation file:

```
pthread_mutex_t A::m;
```

Answer (score 0):

Template has got nothing to do with the linker error you are getting. What you did inside the class is a declaration. You need to define the static variable outside the class so that memory is allocated and initialized.